# how to pass the data from one user control to another user Control both are placed in default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

how to pass the data from one user control to another user Control both are placed in default.aspx

i have two user controls i.e `uc1.ascx` and `uc2.ascx`  both are placed into `Default.aspx` page .

`uc1.ascx  contains --> one Dropdown List ,`

`uc2.ascx contains  ---> Repeater control`

while Dropdown list selected index changed  , i want to chatng the `uc2.aspx` -->`Repeater control` data based on `dropdown Selection`.

Thanks

Comment: if both of your usercontrols are within a page you have number of ways to do this. one would be QueryString, There other things like Cookie or Session

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with event BubbleEvent..

**my event args** I using it for transport selected data

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**user control 1 named uc1**

```
public partial class uc1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void uc1Dorpdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // event bubbling
        RaiseBubbleEvent(this, new MyEventArgs
        {
            Value = this.uc1Dorpdown.SelectedItem.Value,
            Text = this.uc1Dorpdown.SelectedItem.Text
        });
    }
}
```

**user control 1 dropdown**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="uc1Dorpdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="uc1Dorpdown_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Item 1" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Item 2" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Item 3" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Item 4" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Item 5" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Item 6" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**user control 2 named uc2**

```
public partial class uc2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // public is important
    public void RepeaterUpdate(MyEventArgs newValue)
    {
       // call repeater update code
    }
}
```

**default aspx**

```
    protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        //handle bubbled event and call uc2 method
        // MyControls.uc1 is uc type -- u can check eventargs type
        if (source is MyControls.uc1)
        {
            this.uc21.RepeaterUpdate((MyEventArgs)args);
        }
        return base.OnBubbleEvent(source, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to create a public property of the page embedding the two user controls and use this property to send data between the two of them.

For this to work you need to cast the this.parent property in the user controls to the type of you page before you can get/set the value. Something like

```
(this.parent as MyPage).MyProperty
```